# JOptionPane using one window for input and output

Tags: java, joptionpane

So I'm working on a little project and I'm looking for the base code for how to do this in JOptionPane. I'm still really new to this side of Java. I'm not looking for a whole lot, I just didn't know where to start.

The program should populate the screen with a JOptionPane window. I need it to be modeled like the picture below. The bottom row is a text input from the user and when they hit the enter key, the text should "refresh/clear" and then the middle string area should populate with both the user input and then just below it the result of an if statement according the the code.

[image]

for example: The user enters in: "Hello".
Then the text input should refresh and the grey box should do this: "User: Hello."
 "Computer: Hello user".

I would really appreciate any and all help on this.

Comment: Is this for a console program, or do you want a fully functional GUI program?

Comment: Its a text based adventure game. I think that lands under console program. I'm not dealing with any images whatsoever haha

Comment: JOptionPanes don't really work like that. They're meant to get a response from the user and sent that information back to either the console or your gui program. But You seem to want to type into the console and get the input into a gui. Which one is it?

Comment: I'm a little confused now haha. What I'm looking for is some kind of way for the user to interact with the text-based adventure game. When I run my large text-based adventure game in eclipse and on that console within eclipse it prints a series of information and then the user has a chance to navigate the text-based game. I'm looking to mimic the console of eclipse. I wasn't sure if JOptionPane was capable of this. Does that clear things up?

Comment: At the moment I use almost nothing but scanners and system.out.println's. But I would like to now "move" the program into some kind of GUI so that I can export as a runnable .jar file.

Comment: Yeah if you want to mimic the console, You need to make a complete gui program. Do you know how to use `Swing` at all? If not, I would take a look at the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). It will show you how to make GUI programs

Comment: Yeah I've dabbled in Swing. I had no clue where to start on the code haha. I usually do stuff like this in Android so yeah... Thanks for the tutorial though! It looks like it will help. If I come up with the code that I needed, I'll post back here

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Just add the imports, and you can run it and see the console. You need to add code to it to get it to anything though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `System.out.println()` into a gui component. Doesn't work like this. You can write a console program and use JOptionPanes to get user input, but the output would be used in the console program. You would need to create a gui program mimic a console.

Here's a basic layout to start you off

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField(30);

    public Game(){
        add(jtf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(jta, BorderLayour.CENTER);

        jta.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new Game();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What I would suggest is since this is a very basic program, I would use an array of String commands and iterate through them.

For example:

```
String[] question = {"Do you want to go to school?",
                     "Do you want to drive or walk?"};

jta.setText(questions[0]);
```

Then in your actionPerformed get the answer from the text field. Use an if statement like

```
if (jtf.getText().equals("yes") {
    jta.append(questions[1]);
}
```

And so on. If you have no idea what I'm talking about, I would really consider using the Swing tutorials I mentioned. There's a lot of info in those tutorials.

Comment: Oh wow... haha I see what you did there. This really, really helps. Thank you so much!